# With what frequency was stoning applied in the Muslim world before the Ottoman empire?

Tags: middle-east

The Wikipedia article [Rajm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajm) says:

> At least a couple of sources (Sadakat Kadri, Max Rodenbeck) have noted that while popular in the abstract, rajm has been infrequently applied in Islamic history. Stonings were recorded just once in all the history of Ottoman Empire, and not at all in Syria during Muslim rule;

The doesn't have any info about the application of stoning during the Rashidun Caliphate, Ummayad Caliphate and the Abbasid Calophate. How many times was it applied in that period of time?

Comment: The answer of this question is very wide, but in most of islamic historical books there is no 'rajm' and there is some weak stories about rajm happn during rashidin era

Comment: I changed "how many times" to "with what frequency." No one can count the actual times. But it might be possible to answer "rarely," "occasionally," "often," or "regularly."